# Implement an "ISA" Relationship in Microsoft Access

Tags: database, ms-access, parent-child, relationship, rdbms

I would like to implement an "ISA" relationship with a for some arbitrary testing tables in Microsoft Access RDBMS. The "Parent" table, say, would have the following column only:

Parent:

- Num (primary key)

And then, I would have the following child tables, which all may have different property types other than the one referencing Parent.Num, and they are called "Child #" where "#" is the number of the child:

Child 1:

- Parent num (primary key, and foreign key referencing Parent.Num)
- Property 1
- Property 2
- ...

Child 2:

- Parent num (primary key, and foreign key referencing Parent.Num)
- Property 1
- Property 2
- ...

Child 3:

- Parent num (primary key, and foreign key referencing Parent.Num)
- Property 1
- Property 2
- ...

I tried making the "Parent" table have a 1-1 relationship with the "Child #" tables, by having the Parent.Num references in all the "Child #" tables refer back to the "Parent" table, and I successfully managed to add these kinds of relationships. However, insertion was a problem here. I successfully managed to add an entry to the first "Child #" to have its "ISA" relationship attached to the "Parent" table, but I was not able to do the same for the other "Child # table". I would like to know if this is a correct example of "ISA" relationship, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The example is correct, insertion should not be a problem if you created relationships *from* Parent table to Child ones. Which error do you receive?

Comment: @SergeyS. So, actually, I tried inserting into the table after I asked the question, and I was able to do so, however, what I want is for the "Parent" table is to have rows that are similar to the following: Row1: "Child 1" row,  Row2: "Child 1" row, Row3: "Child 3" row, Row4: "Child 2" row, ...etc. I.e. have for each row to only have one 1-1 relationship with either of the "Child #" tables?

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism, which can prevent inserting row with same parent id to child tables, however you can use data macro. Create Before Change data macro for each of child tables and check there if the row with same parent id already exists in other child tables, generate error and cancel inserting if yes.

Comment: @SergeyS. Wow, I was thinking the EXACT same thing, but thanks for pointing that out!! However, I hate coding macros for insertion, deletion, and update for Microsoft Access database tables, as you cannot program them in a programming language like VBA but rather the drag-and-drop programming blocks which is kinda limited (I'm not referring to the client side programming here). Anyways, thanks for your help!!

Comment: You can use VBA functions in DataMacro, no problem. Just create public function and call it from any action like `SetField` of `If`. VBA code should be located in current code base (not in backend)